# Do most countries adopt a "know-your-customers" approach to prevent chemicals from being used by potential drug-traffickers?

Tags: united-states, china, international, drugs

> Certain precursors used in the production of fentanyl are
> internationally classified as unscheduled chemicals and legal to
> produce in China and export. Beijing argues that it cannot restrict
> the export of precursors that are not illegal.
>
> **The U.S. has repeatedly called on China to adopt a
> "know-your-customer" approach such as identifying and verifying
> customer identities to ensure that these chemicals are not sold to
> likely drug traffickers and to alert authorities about such buyers.**
>
> However, in an interview with Newsweek in September 2022, Qin Gang,
> the then-Chinese ambassador to the U.S., said that approach "goes far
> beyond the obligations of countries under the United Nations
> Convention on Drug Control."

https://www.voanews.com/a/china-us-fentanyl-agreement-restarts-stalled-cooperative-fight-against-deadly-drug-/7360424.html

Do most countries adopt a "know-your-customers" approach to prevent chemicals from being used by potential drug-traffickers? I was thinking that most developed countries do this, but I couldn't find any information that confirmed that this was the case.